# Not able to call the GetColor or the SetColor method inside FunctionOne or FunctionTwo

Tags: c++, class, oop

i copied this simple code from a book to play with it while learning C++. however, i can't call the `GetColor` or the `SetColor` method inside either `FunctionOne` or `FunctionTwo`. I have tried writing `theCat->GetColor;` , `theCat->SetColor("yellow");` inside both of the function but none of them seems to work. I wanted to know if it is actually possible to call these methods inside the functions. If so, how?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class SimpleCat {
public:
    SimpleCat();
    SimpleCat(SimpleCat&);
    ~SimpleCat();
    void SetColor(string newColor) { color = newColor; }
    string GetColor() { return color; }
private:
    string color;
};

SimpleCat::SimpleCat() {
    cout << "Simple cat constructor…\n";
color:"";
}

SimpleCat::SimpleCat(SimpleCat&) {
    cout << "SimpleCat copy constructor…\n";
}

SimpleCat::~SimpleCat() {
    cout << "SimpleCat destructor…\n";
}

SimpleCat FunctionOne(SimpleCat theCat);
SimpleCat* FunctionTwo(SimpleCat* theCat);

int main() {
    cout << "Making a cat…\n";
    SimpleCat Frisky;
    cout << "Calling FunctionOne…\n";
    FunctionOne(Frisky);
    cout << "Calling FunctionTwo…\n";
    Frisky.SetColor("yellow");
    FunctionTwo(&Frisky);
    cout << Frisky.GetColor();
    return 0;

}

// function one passes by value
SimpleCat FunctionOne(SimpleCat theCat) {
    cout << "Function One, Returning…\n";
    return theCat;
}

SimpleCat* FunctionTwo(SimpleCat* theCat) {
    cout << "Function Two, Returning...\n";
    return theCat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `FunctionOne()`, `theCat` is passed in *by value*.  You have to use the `.` operator to access its members:

```cpp
SimpleCat FunctionOne(SimpleCat theCat) {
    theCat.SetColor("red");
    cout << "Function One, Color is " << theCat.GetColor() << "\n";
    cout << "Function One, Returning…\n";
    return theCat;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/6yyj3p)

Because `theCat` is passed by value, it is a *copy* of the caller's `SimpleCat` object (ie, `Frisky` in `main()`) so any changes you make to `theCat` WILL NOT be reflected in the original.  If you want the original to be modified, pass it in *by reference* instead:

```cpp
SimpleCat& FunctionThree(SimpleCat &theCat) {
    theCat.SetColor("brown");
    cout << "Function One, Color is " << theCat.GetColor() << "\n";
    cout << "Function One, Returning…\n";
    return theCat;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/6yyj3p)

---

Inside `FunctionTwo()`, `theCat` is passed in *by pointer*.  You have to use the `->` operator to access its members (despite your claim, this works just fine):

```cpp
SimpleCat* FunctionTwo(SimpleCat* theCat) {
    theCat->SetColor("blue");
    cout << "Function Two, Color is " << theCat->GetColor() << "\n";
    cout << "Function Two, Returning…\n";
    return theCat;
}
```

Because `theCat` is passed by pointer, it points to the caller's `SimpleCat` object (ie `Frisky` in `main()`) so any changes you make to `theCat` WILL be reflected in the original.

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/6yyj3p)

---

That being said, there are some other issues with your code.

- The copy constructor is declared wrong.  It needs to be:

  ```cpp
  SimpleCat(const SimpleCat&);
  ```
- `GetColor()` should be declared `const`:

  ```cpp
  string GetColor() const { return color; }
  ```
- `SimpleCat`'s default constructor is not initializing `color` correctly.
  The statement `color:"";` has no effect, it should be:

  ```cpp
  SimpleCat::SimpleCat() {
      cout << "Simple cat constructor…\n";
      color = "";
  }
  ```

  Or, use the constructor's [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) instead:

  ```cpp
  SimpleCat::SimpleCat() : color("") {
      cout << "Simple cat constructor…\n";
  }
  ```

  However, `std::string` has its own default constructor, so there is never a reason to initialize a `string` to `""` manually.
- `SimpleCat`'s copy constructor is not making a copy of `color` at all.

  ```
  SimpleCat::SimpleCat(const SimpleCat &src) {
      cout << "SimpleCat copy constructor…\n";
      color = src.color;
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  SimpleCat::SimpleCat(const SimpleCat &src) : color(src.color) {
      cout << "SimpleCat copy constructor…\n";
  }
  ```

Comment: damn, beat me to it. Nice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one more question. Why can't we declare `FunctionTwo` as `SimpleCat FunctionTwo(SimpleCat* theCat);`? Why should it be written as `SimpleCat* FunctionTwo(SimpleCat* theCat);`?

Comment: @EgoObsidian what makes you think you can't declare it that way? You can. But, the return value is then being returned *by value*, so if you are going to return `theCat` then you will have to dereference it, eg: `return *theCat;` Otherwise you will have to return a whole new `SimpleCat` object.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh I see. The compiler was giving an error and that confused me.

Comment: @EgoObsidian Well yeah, because you can't assign a `SimpleCat*` pointer to a `SimpleCat` object.  But you can dereference the pointer to access the object it is pointing at, and then you can assign that object to another object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to call these methods inside the functions. For example:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class SimpleCat {
public:
  SimpleCat();
  SimpleCat(SimpleCat&);
  ~SimpleCat();
  void SetColor(string newColor) { color = newColor; }
  string GetColor() { return color; }
private:
  string color;
};

SimpleCat::SimpleCat() {
  cout << "Simple cat constructor...\n";
color:"";
}

SimpleCat::SimpleCat(SimpleCat&) {
  cout << "SimpleCat copy constructor...\n";
}

SimpleCat::~SimpleCat() {
  cout << "SimpleCat destructor...\n";
}

SimpleCat FunctionOne(SimpleCat theCat);
SimpleCat* FunctionTwo(SimpleCat* theCat);

int main() {
  cout << "Making a cat...\n";
  SimpleCat Frisky;
  cout << "Calling FunctionOne...\n";
  FunctionOne(Frisky);
  cout << "Calling FunctionTwo...\n";
  Frisky.SetColor("yellow"); // set yellow
  FunctionTwo(&Frisky); // we pass address to object as a pointer param func & change color value
  cout << Frisky.GetColor(); // print new changed color value
  return 0;

}

// function one passes by value
SimpleCat FunctionOne(SimpleCat theCat) {
  string color_str = theCat.GetColor();
  cout << "Function One, Returning...\n";
  return theCat;
}

SimpleCat* FunctionTwo(SimpleCat* theCat) {
  theCat->SetColor("new_color");
  cout << "Function Two, Returning...\n";
  return theCat;
}
```